# React JS create dynamic element on json loop

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components

I am using react JS to build a form creator. Right now I'm focused on the process of rendering the element inside the form, basically it's a div containing some other divs, as a child.
I have my main component (Form) and some child that can be different components, like textbox or dropdown, and so on, with a set of common properties, and a set of specific properties (for instance the dropdown options are not inserted in the textbox component).

I'm also fetching the data from an API that respond with a json with a "type" parameter ("textbox", "dropdown", etc).

I'm looping on the json, and for sure I can just check the type and IF it's textbox create a textbox, IF it's a dropdown create a dropdown... But i think there is a better solution.

This is my code:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';
import Textbox from './Textbox';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';

function Form(){

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(loading){
        fetchComponents()
    }
    
});


const fetchComponents = () => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/position'
    })
    .then(res => {      
        setComponents(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
    });
}

const allItems = () => {

    return( 
        components.map((component, key) => {
            /** THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CREATE THE ELEMENT DYNAMICALLY */
            const  options = JSON.parse(component.options);
            if(component.type === 'textbox'){
                return <Textbox 
                            key={component.id}
                            id={ component.id}  
                            name={component.name} 
                            default={{
                                x: options.position.x,
                                y: options.position.y,
                                width: options.size.width,
                                height: options.size.height
                            }}
                            minWidth={100}
                            minHeight={100}
                            resizeGrid={[20, 20]}
                            dragGrid={[20, 20]}
                            label={component.label}
                            value={component.value}
                            bounds="window"
                        />
            }
            if(component.type === 'dropdown'){
                return <Dropdown 
                            key={component.id}
                            id={ component.id}  
                            name={component.name} 
                            default={{
                                x: options.position.x,
                                y: options.position.y,
                                width: options.size.width,
                                height: options.size.height
                            }}
                            minWidth={100}
                            minHeight={100}
                            resizeGrid={[20, 20]}
                            dragGrid={[20, 20]}
                            label={component.label}
                            value={component.value}
                            dropdown_options={component.dropdown_options}
                            bounds="window"
            />
            }

        })
    )
}


return(
    <div>
          
    
    <div className="box background-quaderno" style={{height: '500px', width: '500px', position: 'relative', overflow: 'auto', padding: '0'}}>
      <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', padding: '0px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>

        {loading ? <></> : allItems()}
        
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You receiving only `component.options` as string so you need to parse it?
First of all
`switch(component.type) {
    case('textbox'): 
        return ...
}`

is better than `if` in your case

Comment: @Lrazerz I though there was a better solution than a switch, just to have the code much more compact and readable.